# How to run command in command prompt?

Tags: cmd, command, command-prompt, sfc, sc

Whenever I try to run any command in cmd, the command does not work, instead it shows me description and usage of that command. I am not being able to run any command.

[Cmd code which should run and the command should work but it is showing the description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBhSe.png)

Comment: It is clear that the command you typed in your Administrator Command Prompt window did not use the correct syntax, which is why it showed you what it was expecting. However your question suggests that the issue is not with the `config` options of `sc.exe` alone, you specifically said **any command in cmd**. Can you provide evidence of these other commands?

Answer (score 0):

`sc` is hypersensitive to whitespace, and unusual in what it wants. Try `sc config trustedinstaller start= auto`, with a space after the equals sign but not before it.